# $-1$ element in $\mathbb{Z}_n^*$, where $n$ is such that $\mathbb{Z}_n^*$ has a primitive root

Tags: elementary-number-theory, totient-function, primitive-roots

Let $n\in\mathbb{N}$ be such that $\mathbb{Z}_n^*$ has a primitive root. Let $a$ be such a primitive root. Is the following true?
$$a^{\frac{\phi(n)}{2}}\equiv-1\mod{n}$$
where $\phi$ is Euler's function.

It all comes down to whether $x^2\equiv 1\mod{n} \Leftrightarrow x\equiv\pm 1\mod{n}$ is a true statement, which I have failed to prove.

Answer (score 1):

If $\mathbb Z_n^*$ has a primitive root, then $a,a^2,a^3,...,a^{\phi(n)}$
are the elements of $\mathbb Z_n^*$. So, there is a unique number $m$
with $1\le m< \phi(n)$ and $a^m=-1$

This implies $a^{2m}=1$. Therefore we have $\phi(n)|2m$ , but $2m<2\phi(n)$.

It follows $2m=\phi(n)$ and therefore $m=\frac{\phi(n)}{2}$ completing the proof.

Note that for $n=2$, $\mathbb Z_n^*$ has only $1$ element , so we must assume $n>2$, otherwise $\frac{\phi(n)}{2}$ is not an integer. In this case, $-1$ and $1$ are different elements and the proof works.